# How to use mock entitymanager that returns fake repository in controller?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mocking, phpunit, entitymanager

In my test I'm trying to mock the entity manager so it'll return a repository that will not connect to the database but instead return a fake value:

In the test according to [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/database.html):

```
  $session = new Session(new MockArraySessionStorage());
  $mockManager = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
  $mockManager->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->will($this->returnValue(new userRepo()));      
  $client = static::createClient();
  $container = $client->getContainer();
  $container->set('session', $session);
  $container->set('doctrine.orm.entity_manager',$mockManager);
  $client->request('POST', '/secured/login'
      ,array('userName'=>'username','password'=>'password'
      ,'rememberMe'=>'on'));
  $response = $client->getResponse();
  //....
```

In test, the userRepo:

```
class userRepo {
  public function isValidUser($userName, $password) {
    echo "this is isvaliduser";
    return $this->getFullUserById(22);
  }
  public function getFullUserById($id){
    echo "this is getfulluserbyid";
    return ["name"=>"someName"];
  }
}
```

In the controller:

```
  public function loginAction(Request $request) {
    $userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository('mytestBundle:User');
    $user=$userRepo->isValidUser($userName,$password);
    $response = new Response();
    //... other code using session and whatnot
    $response->headers->set("Content-Type", 'application/json');
    $response->setContent(json_encode($user));
    return $response;
  }
```

The fake repository is never used as the echo doesn't show up when I run the test.

Up until creating the mock I think it's working as it should but setting the mock may be the problem `$container->set('doctrine.orm.entity_manager',$mockManager);` as the controller when calling `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` gets the actual entity manager and not the mock one.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm, every time I spend a lot of time trying to figure stuff out; right after I descide to post a question the answer shows itself in yet another google search and trying that:

Solution was:

```
  $container->set('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', $mockManager);
```

Comment: thanks it works... but do you have an idea why I can't simply mock the "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface" class instead... because this is the one I'm using in my tested code... and not "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"

Comment: @Oliboy50 No, sorry I can't help you with that. It's been a while since I've worked with doctrine and I'd imagine things have changed as well.

Answer (score 0):

$container->set('doctrine.orm.entity_manager',$mockManager);

Comment: please elaborate your answer always